# Cumulative Sum | Exclude attribute from calculation

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am trying to do Cumulative Sum/ Running Total using the function below so the user can use any date level, but the requirement is to ignore some of the attributes from the calculation.

Function used:

```
SUM(NULL:Axis(1).Item(0).Item(Axis(1).Item(0).Count-1).Hierarchy.CurrentMember, [Measures].[ Number of Ticket])
```

Example:
The table below shows the Cumulative Sum as expected

[Example - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4eCr.png)

Here by adding another attribute, Program Remaining, as shown below, its changes the Cumulative behavior, Because Excel will add that attribute to the grouping so it reset the cumulative sum:

[Example - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um0jI.png)

Is there a way that I can exclude the Program Remaining attribute from the calculation (I have another 4 attributes that I want to exclude) so that the cumulative can be increased just like the first table even with adding these attribute.

I really appreciate any help

Comment: Do you mark the useful answers to your questions as answers?

Comment: yes, I do. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: Thanks, Moaz, do you know if its possible to do the above?

Comment: Let me get back to you in 30mins

Comment: I am afraid that you have uploaded the same pic twice, can you check that.

Comment: Can you check now. Thanks

Comment: what is programs remaining? is it a attribute hierarchy or user hierarchy?

Comment: It’s an attribute hierarchy. So basically, there is another dimension has 6 attributes which include the Programs Remaining. I am looking for logic to having the cumulative not to reset if I use this attribute and another 2 attributes from the same dimension. another word, the dimension has 6 attributes, 3 of the attribute it's ok to have the cumulative reset. However, there are another 3 attributes like the Remaining Program, if I use this in the PivotTable should not reset the calculation and keep cumulating the number even if the Remaining Program changed. Please let me know if any question

Comment: so to sum it up there is a set of attribute of various dimensions that you want the running total to ignore, and for the remaining the running total to respond?

Comment: Yes, so the running total to ignore for the function to keep the number cumulating and not to reset the number and the others is to reset is fine. There are going to be two diminutions that have these types of attributes, and each dimension of these two has 6 attributes. 3 attribute from each dimension not to reset the numbers and just keep cumulating. Hopefully, I am not confusing you.

Comment: The query should work for you, let me know incase of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below sample query

```
with 
member 
[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountRunningtotal]
as 
case when [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = null then null 
else 
sum({[Product].[Subcategory].firstchild:[Product].[Subcategory].currentmember},[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
end
select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],
[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountRunningtotal]
} on columns,

non empty
([Date].[Calendar Year].[Calendar Year],[Date].[Calendar Quarter of Year].[Calendar Quarter of Year],
[Product].[Category].[Category],[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory])
on 
rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

[image]

So I explored the sample sent, Your only solutions is to keep the date in the inner most position, your query qouted above will break if you are not using entire members of an attribute.

Comment: Hi Moaz, I really appreciate that you are looking into this. There are many other dimensions that will be used and the user needs the freedom of using any date level that's why I am using Axis(see above). it's by using any dimension, any date level, and the outstanding fix is for the cumulative not to reset and keep cumulative even is the ids/ number changes for some of the attributes. I know is not an easy task that's why I want to find out is someone with great skills of MDX like you can do it or not? again, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @Mike you are welcome, how about genrating MDX at runtime on the suggested structure? is that possible?

Comment: @Mike can you share your entire query? I want to reproduce the issue on Adventureworks and try to solve it.

Comment: Hi Moaz,  I got the requirement changed. How can we have the cumulative keep increasing no matter what attributes or dimensions are used and the cumulative never reset? This is the function I am using because it needs to be used at any date level.  I really appreciate your time.                                                                                                                            SUM(NULL:Axis(1).Item(0).Item(Axis(1).Item(0).Count-1).Hierarchy.CurrentMember, [Measures].[ Number of Tickets])

Comment: @Mike send me your query or make a sample on adventure works, and I will try to solve it. What about generating custom MDX based on what user selects

Comment: Thanks, Moaz, how can I attach files? I have sample cube and backup